# CDH 4.1.1. Hive JDBC connection

Tags: jdbc, hadoop, hive, cloudera

I have pretty strange problem. I do have an CDH 4.1.1 cluster with Cloudera manager free installed.
Beeswax works fine, hive CLI utility works fine.

Not nothing listens to port 10000 (a default port for Hive JDBC connectivity). I do have standalone test CDH 4.1.1 VMWare image (you can download it from Cloudera site). There is the same situation but there 10000 is opened and I can query Hive.

What do I do wrong? Why 10000 is closed? What do I have to make it work on my cluster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so CDH 4.1.1 demo image does have running Hive Thrift server as a service. If we are working with CDH cluster which is under contorol of Cloudera manager free, we have to do:

goto **Cloodera Manager Free (CMFree)**

*Services»

Service hue1»*

fill the field: **Hive Configuration Safety Valve**

```
<property>
<name>hive.server2.thrift.min.worker.threads</name>
<value>5</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>hive.server2.thrift.max.worker.threads</name>
<value>100</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>hive.server2.thrift.port</name>
<value>10000</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>hive.server2.thrift.bind.host</name>
<value>10.66.48.23</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>hive.server2.authentication</name>
<value>NONE</value>
</property>

<!-- TODO: add concurrency support-->
<property>
<name>hive.support.concurrency</name>
<value>false</value><!-- -should be true -->
</property>

<!-- do it later
<property>
<name>hive.zookeeper.quorum</name>
<description>Zookeeper quorum used by Hive's Table Lock Manager</description>
<value>zk1.yoyodyne.com,zk2.yoyodyne.com,zk3.yoyodyne.com</value>
</property>
-->
```

Restart service

And then start hive thrift server:

```
[devops@cdh-1 ~]$ sudo -u hdfs /usr/bin/hive --service hiveserver
```

Here you can see how it can be "demonized" on CentOS

http://blog.milford.io/2010/06/daemonizing-the-apache-hive-thrift-server-on-centos/